# RTL_BITMAP the same as BitArray in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke

Can someone tell me if the `RTL_BITMAP` structure ([for use with `RtlInitializeBitMap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) in C++ is the same as a [`BitArray` in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.BitArray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? If not, is there anything that can be changed to make it the same? The reason I ask is because I am trying to port some C++ code to C# and some of the code utilizes a code that converts the `Bitmap` in [`VOLUME_BITMAP_BUFFER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365726%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to a `RTL_BITMAP` structure.

Comment: `Do not directly access the members of this structure. Drivers that have dependencies on member locations or that access member values directly might not remain compatible with future versions of the Windows operating system.`

Comment: You should probably keep that as an `IntPtr`.

Comment: I've added some more details so hopefully you can give me a better answer

Comment: The RtlXxx functions are part of the layer that glues the documented WINAPI to the undocumented native operating system.  Most of these functions are undocumented, some squeaked out of the years when they were useful for debugging or back-filling a capability that the WINAPI did not have.  You should never take a dependency on them, Microsoft doesn't promise to keep them compatible in future Windows versions.  So just scratch this idea.  The standard C++ type that models an array of bits is `std::vector<bool>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone tell me if the `RTL_BITMAP` structure (for use with `RtlInitializeBitMap`) in C++ is the same as a `BitArray` in C#?

Well, they are not the same in as much as being identical. But these two types (and the associated `RtlXXX` functions in the case of `RTL_BITMAP`) essentially implement the same data structure. Namely a compact array of boolean values.

There is quite a lot of high level functionality available for the `RTL_BITMAP` type that is not offered by the `BitArray` type. However, you may very well not need any of that, and any that you do need is readily implemented on top of `BitArray`.

So in summary, `BitArray` seems like a good starting place for your translation, based on the information that you have provided.